# How to Programmatically make permission .denied the PhotoLibrary Authorization

Tags: ios, swift, phphotolibrary

In my app I have a Settings section which should be able to handle the app-privacy the same as the iOS settings does (using on/off switches).

I know how to gain authorization for photo library but is there a way to change the permission to .denied manually?

Here is my Authorizing code:

```
let status = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
if( status != .authorized ){
    PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { status in
        switch status {
        case .authorized:
            switchButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "SwitchOn"), for: .normal) // Change the button image for Switch On
            break
        case .denied, .restricted: break
            // 
        case .notDetermined: break
            // 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In iOS/watchOS, .. there is no way to change permission manually. All the permission must be acquired from user, and changed from setting menu. You can let user go to the app setting page though.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? You should be happy that user allows some privacy settings because you need it for some purpose, dont you?

Comment: @RobertDresler I know what u mean :D. Im trying to implement clients requirement here :( . User should be able to enable and disable permissions inside the App same as the settings.

Comment: @LahiruPinto clients are sometimes crazy... tell him that this isn't possible and if he wouldn't trust you, give me his phone nubmer... 

Comment: @RobertDresler LoL I have suggested to open the IOS App Settings from there :D